# Get the height of the div instead of window

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an animation that happens based on the page scroll. I'm able to do it based on the page height, etc. But how do I do it based on the div height/when it hits this div? Because the div will live closer to the bottom of the page and animation needs to happen when you get to that div.

P.S. my div has of Section assigned like so - className={styles.Section}

```
  onScroll(scrollConfig) {
    const { defaultProgress, totalRowHeight, adjustProgress, totalCy } = scrollConfig;
    const offset = window.pageYOffset;
    const wheight = window.innerHeight;
    const html = document.documentElement;
    const docheight = Math.max(document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight,
      html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight);
    const progress = offset / (docheight - wheight);

    // Get pos count based on scroll position

    const pos = defaultProgress + 13 + progress * (totalRowHeight - adjustProgress);

    this.notes.map((obj, index) => {
      const node = this.notes[index].ref.current;
      const noteOffset = node.getBoundingClientRect();
      const rowHeight = noteOffset.height;
      obj["rowHeight"] = rowHeight;
      obj["circleStrokeColor"] = pos < obj.cy ? style.beforeColor : style.afterColor;
    });
    // console.log(adjustHeight, pos);

    this.setState({
      afterLineHeight: pos > totalCy ? totalCy : pos
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean div height or the (top) position of the div compared to page top?

Comment: well, both I think? I need the animation to happen when you scroll into the element (it's a slow reveal)

Answer (score 2):

`HTMLElement.offsetHeight` // read-only property returns the height of an element, including vertical padding and borders, as an integer.

`HTMLElement.offsetTop` // read-only property returns the distance of the current element relative to the top of the offsetParent node.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect candidate for [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). With IO you can observe elements and react to them once they get into view, leave the view or intersect with other elements.

It's also much more performant than using `scroll` event.

First, you have to set the options for your IO and create a new observer with these options:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here the `callback` function would get called everytime an element is 100% getting into view or leaving the view. You can also specify a root element then the callback will be triggered once the element intersects with this root element.

Then you have to specify the element(s) you want to observe:

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('.elements');
targets.forEach(target => {
  // if you only have 1 element (like with document.getElementById) you can call .observe directly
  observer.observe(target);
});
```

Last you have to specify what happens once the observer is triggered:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element:
    //   entry.boundingClientRect
    //   entry.intersectionRatio
    //   entry.intersectionRect
    //   entry.isIntersecting
    //   entry.rootBounds
    //   entry.target
    //   entry.time
  });
};
```

You can also [unobserve an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) if you only want to trigger this once.

There is also a [polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers. This polyfill uses scroll event to mimic the behaviour.

Lastly, have a [look at this example](https://alligator.io/js/intersection-observer/), I think this shows your desired output? (Scroll down until you see the images getting animated)